# Equal operator: pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, pointers

In one of my classes I included a pointer to a member function:

```
private:
void (class_name::*_pf)(double&, gc::mag::coefficient&, gc::mag::st&, const int&) const;
```

This pointer either points to `function1` or `function2` of class `class_name`.

Now when I have two object of class `class_name`, how can I check whether the `_pf` pointers are pointing to the same member function (that is, are they both pointing at `function1` or `function2`)?

Comment: While C++ will certainly allow you to use this approach, it sounds like having a base class with a virtual member from which you derive two other classes that implement the two types of functions would be a better approach.  Modern C++ usage is to moving away from direct use of pointers since it is a source of defects.  And this sounds like tricky code that will be a source of defects.

Comment: When you have two function pointers, you can simply compare them with `if (_pf1 == _pf2)`. Note that this is completely independent of any instances of class `class_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
if (this->_pf == other._pf)
```

---

Example :

```
#include <iostream>

class class_name
{
  public:
  void function1(int) {}
  void function2(int) {}
};

class test
{
    public:
    test(void (class_name::*pf)(int))
    : _pf(pf)
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const test& other)
    {
        return (this->_pf == other._pf);
    }

  public:
    void (class_name::*_pf)(int);
};

int main()
{
   test t(&class_name::function1);
   test t2(&class_name::function2);

   std::cout << std::boolalpha << (t == t2) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```